# Effects of a class constructor on its attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, constructor

How is that the `__str__` method in the first example return the string successfully when `self.foo` hasn't been defined:

```
class foo:
    foo = 'K-Dawg'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.foo

obj = foo()
print obj
#K-Dawg
```

And when I create a class constructor method *`__init__`*, This produces:

> AttributeError: foo instance has no attribute 'foo'

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        foo = 'K-Dawg'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.foo

obj = foo()
print obj
```

***Why is `self.foo` successfully returned in the first example and not in the second?***

What effects does an class constructor have on its attributes?

**EDIT:
I do know that changing `foo = 'K-Dawg'` to `self.foo = 'K-Dawg'` would print *K-Dawg* successfully, But What I'm asking is why is that the attribute `foo` in the first example gets to be called using `self.foo`**

Comment: Just on a side note, `__init__` is not a constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Modified first program**

```
class foo:
    foo = 'K-Dawg'

    def __str__(self):
        print dir(self)
        return self.foo

obj = foo()
print obj
```

**Modified second program**

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print locals()
        foo = 'K-Dawg'
        print locals()

    def __str__(self):
        print locals()
        return self.foo

obj = foo()
print obj
```

I just included few print statements. If you look at the outputs of each of the programs you ll be able to figure out what exactly is happening.

The first program will print

```
['__doc__', '__module__', '__str__', 'foo']
K-Dawg
```

We can see that the `foo` is already there in the object. Actually, in this case, `foo` is a class variable (nothing related to the class instances. If you are from C, C++ or JAVA background, this can be considered as a static variable which is bound to a class not to an Object.)

The second program will print

```
{'self': <__main__.foo instance at 0x7f528aa90488>}
{'self': <__main__.foo instance at 0x7f528aa90488>, 'foo': 'K-Dawg'}
{'self': <__main__.foo instance at 0x7f11f236d488>}
AttributeError: foo instance has no attribute 'foo'
```

It evidently shows us that variable `foo` got created in the `__init__` function but it is not available when it reaches `__str__`. It means the `foo` variable which was created in `__init__` is local to that function.

If you wanted to create the variable in the object, you should do something like this

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print locals()
        self.foo = 'K-Dawg'   # Note the self keyword at the beginning
        print locals()

    def __str__(self):
        print locals()
        return self.foo

obj = foo()
print obj
```

**Output**

```
{'self': <__main__.foo instance at 0x7fe0e2da24d0>}
{'self': <__main__.foo instance at 0x7fe0e2da24d0>}
{'self': <__main__.foo instance at 0x7fe0e2da24d0>}
K-Dawg
```

`self` points to the current instance of the class and we are attaching a variable called `foo` by doing `self.foo = 'K-Dawg'`. That is why this works.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you have created a class attribute `foo` --- one attribute shared among all instances of the class.  When you try to access `self.foo`, if the instance does not have its own `foo` attribute, it reads the one from the class.

In the second case, you are not creating an attribute at all.  `foo` in `__init__` is just a local variable.  If you want to create an instance variable you need:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.foo = 'K-Dawg'
```